# my popup should show when score = 6, but i cant make it work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the popup show when score is equal to 6. and then when you press the button the page should reload. But i can't seem to make it work. i tried the function with the if-statement but it doens't work. so i don't know what to do or how to do it. so i would enjoy it if someone could help me out :)

```js
//Function for the dropdown content
function dropdownTips() {
    document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  
  window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowncontent");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  //the game
  
  // Declares global variables
  let score = 0,
    cardToMatch = null;
  
  // Calls `flipCard` on any click
  window.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
  
  
  // Defines the click listener
  function flipCard(event) {
  
    // Identifies the card where the click happened
    const card = event.target.closest(".card");
  
    // Ignores irrelevant/invalid clicks
    if (!card || card.classList.contains("open")) {
      return;
    }
  
    // A valid click always opens the card
    card.classList.add("open");
  
    // If this is the 1st card of 2, remember it
    if (cardToMatch === null) {
      cardToMatch = card;
    } else {
  
  
      // If it's the 2nd card, compare types
      // If they match...
      if (card.dataset.type === cardToMatch.dataset.type) {
  
        // ...Increment score and show it in the DOM
        updateScoreDisplay(++score);
      }
  
      // If they don't...
      else {
        // ...Flip both cards back over
        setTimeout((first, second) => {
          first.classList.remove("open");
          second.classList.remove("open");
          
        }, 3000, card, cardToMatch);
        
        // Either way, next click will be the 1st of 2
      }
      
      cardToMatch = null;
    }
  }
  
  function updateScoreDisplay(newScore) {
    // Syncs the user-displayed value w/ score
    const element = document.querySelector(".score span");
    element.textContent = newScore;
  }

  // popup section
  
  let popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

  popup = function() {
      if (score === 6) {
          popup.style.display ="block";
          console.log("hello");
      }
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color:#00005e;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 38%;
  right: 40%;
  width: 355px;
}

/*The 'tips?' button and the drop down content*/
header button {
display: inline-flex;
position:absolute;
align-items: center;
right: 2%;
top: 15%;
bottom: 15%;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color:white;
color: #00005e;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
border-color: transparent;
}

header button:hover {
opacity: 80%;
}


.dropdowncontent {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
background-color:#010169;
min-width: 160px;
max-width: 400px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
z-index: 100;

}

.dropdowncontent li {
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.advise{
font-size: 19px;
}

.passwordtips {
font-size: 30px;
left: 20%;
}

.show {
display:block;
}

/*The link in the dropdowncontent*/
a {
text-decoration: underline;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

/*The score counter*/
.score {
  color: #01016e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/*The game section*/
.sectionOne {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #00005e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

/*The sections content*/
.wrapper {
width: 99%;
height: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 183px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.card{
background-color: #01016e;
color: white;
margin: 10px 10px;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.card h2{
  padding: 2px;
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}

.card:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.open{
animation: flip .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes flip {
from { 
  background: #00005e;
  font-size: 0;
}
to{
  background: rgb(20, 73, 185);
  font-size:17px;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
}

/* pop up section */
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 50.5vh;
  top: 14%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: none;
}

.congrats {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  top: 20%;
  color: #00005e;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.matches {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  top: 35%;
  color: #00005e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.playAgain {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 65%;
  left: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #00005e;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*The 'DID YOU KNOW' over the ticker*/
.facts {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 15px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #00005e;
}

/*The facts ticker*/
.tcontainer {
max-width: 1100px;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.ticker-wrap {
width: 100%;
padding-left: 100%; 
background-color: #00005e;
}

@keyframes ticker {
0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
.ticker-move {
 display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-right: 100%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: ticker;
animation-duration: 55s;
}
.ticker-move:hover{
animation-play-state: paused; 
}

.ticker-item{
display: inline-block; 
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-right: 3em;
color: white;
min-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
}


/*The pause button for the ticker*/
.pause {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.pausebutton {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #00005e;
color: white;
border-style: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.pausebutton:hover {
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>The Password Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>THE PASSWORD GAME</h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropdownTips()" class="dropbtn">TIPS?</button>
            <div class="dropdowncontent" id="mydropdown" >
                <ul>
                    <li class="passwordtips">Tips for making strong passwords: </li>
                    <li class="advise">1. Use 16 characters or more (use both uppercase and lowercase letters, number and symbols.)</li>
                    <li class="advise">2. Never use the same password twice.</li>
                    <li class="advise">3. Use a password manager.</li>
                    <li class="advise">4. Don't write your passwords down on paper.</li>
                    <li class="advise">5. Don't share your passwords with others.</li>
                    <li class="advise">6. Change your password after a breach.</li>
                    <li class="advise">7. Sign up for data breach notifications. (like <a href="https://haveibeenpwned.com/" target="_blank">haveibeenpwned.com</a>).</li>
                    <li class="advise">8. Check your accounts regularly for any suspicious activity. </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="score">Score:<span> 0</span></div>

    <section class="sectionOne">
        <div class="wrapper" id="card-deck">
            <div class="card" data-type="1"><h2>What information should you NEVER use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerSix" class="card"  data-type="6"><h2>1 log in</h2></div>
            <div id="cardThree" class="card"  data-type="3"><h2>When should you ALWAYS change your password?</h2></div>
            <div id="anserFive" class="card"  data-type="5"><h2>suspicious activity</h2></div>
            <div id="cardTwo" class="card"  data-type="2"><h2>Who is it okay to tell your password to?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>16</h2></div>
            <div id="answerThree" class="card" data-type="3"><h2>After a data breach</h2></div>
            <div id="answerTwo" class="card" data-type="2"><h2>No one</h2></div>
            <div id="CardSix" class="card" data-type="6"><h2>For how many log ins is it okay to use the same password?</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>How many characters should you AT LEAST use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div class="card" data-card="firstSet" data-type="1"><h2>Name and Birthday</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFive" class="card" data-type="5"><h2>What should you regularly look for in your accounts?</h2></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="popup">
        <h3 class="congrats">Congratulations!</h3>
        <h3 class="matches">You got 6/6 matches</h3>
        <button class="playAgain">Play again?</button>
    </section>

    <div class="facts">
        <h2>DID YOU KNOW?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">There is a hacker attack every 39 seconds.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">90% of passwords can be cracked in less than 6 hours.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">80% of hacking related breaches are linked to insufficient passwords.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">59% use their name or birthday in their password.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">6.850.000 passwords are getting hacked each day.</div>
      </div></div></div>

    <div class="pause">
        <p>Hold your mouse over to pause</p>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Score remains the same for me how does this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this code which doesnt run when score is incremented

```js
popup = function() {
      if (score === 6) {
          popup.style.display ="block";
          console.log("hello");
      }
  }
```

so i've created a function to check the score like this

```js
let popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
function showPopup() {
      if (score === 6) {
          popup.style.display ="block";
          console.log("hello");
      }
  }
```

And call the `showPopup` function when score is added like this

```js
if (card.dataset.type === cardToMatch.dataset.type) {
        // ...Increment score and show it in the DOM
        updateScoreDisplay(++score);
        showPopup();
      }
```

full code :

```js
    //Function for the dropdown content
    let popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
    function showPopup() {
          if (score > 0) {
              popup.style.display ="block";
              console.log("hello");
          }
      }
    function dropdownTips() {
        document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }
      
      
      window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      
          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowncontent");
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
          }
        }
      });
      
      //the game
      
      // Declares global variables
      let score = 0,
        cardToMatch = null;
      
      // Calls `flipCard` on any click
      window.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
      
      
      // Defines the click listener
      function flipCard(event) {
      
        // Identifies the card where the click happened
        const card = event.target.closest(".card");
      
        // Ignores irrelevant/invalid clicks
        if (!card || card.classList.contains("open")) {
          return;
        }
      
        // A valid click always opens the card
        card.classList.add("open");
      
        // If this is the 1st card of 2, remember it
        if (cardToMatch === null) {
          cardToMatch = card;
        } else {
      
      
          // If it's the 2nd card, compare types
          // If they match...
          if (card.dataset.type === cardToMatch.dataset.type) {
      
            // ...Increment score and show it in the DOM
            updateScoreDisplay(++score);
            showPopup();
          }
      
          // If they don't...
          else {
            // ...Flip both cards back over
            setTimeout((first, second) => {
              first.classList.remove("open");
              second.classList.remove("open");
              
            }, 3000, card, cardToMatch);
            
            // Either way, next click will be the 1st of 2
          }
          
          cardToMatch = null;
        }
      }
      
      function updateScoreDisplay(newScore) {
        // Syncs the user-displayed value w/ score
        const element = document.querySelector(".score span");
        element.textContent = newScore;
      }
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    header {
      background-color:#00005e;
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
    }

    header h1 {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 38%;
      right: 40%;
      width: 355px;
    }

    /*The 'tips?' button and the drop down content*/
    header button {
    display: inline-flex;
    position:absolute;
    align-items: center;
    right: 2%;
    top: 15%;
    bottom: 15%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:white;
    color: #00005e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: transparent;
    }

    header button:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
    }


    .dropdowncontent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color:#010169;
    min-width: 160px;
    max-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 100;

    }

    .dropdowncontent li {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    .advise{
    font-size: 19px;
    }

    .passwordtips {
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 20%;
    }

    .show {
    display:block;
    }

    /*The link in the dropdowncontent*/
    a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
    }

    a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    /*The score counter*/
    .score {
      color: #01016e;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    /*The game section*/
    .sectionOne {
      max-width: 1100px;
      height: 550px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border-radius: 7px;
      border-color: #00005e;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 5px;
      position: relative;
    }

    /*The sections content*/
    .wrapper {
    width: 99%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 183px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    }

    .card{
    background-color: #01016e;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .card h2{
      padding: 2px;
      transform: scale(-1,1);
    }

    .card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .open{
    animation: flip .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    @keyframes flip {
    from { 
      background: #00005e;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    to{
      background: rgb(20, 73, 185);
      font-size:17px;
      transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    }
    }

    /* pop up section */
    #popup {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;
      z-index: 100;
      right: 50.5vh;
      top: 14%;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
      border-radius: 8px;
      display: none;
    }

    .congrats {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 40px;
      top: 20%;
      color: #00005e;
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .matches {
      position: relative;
      height: 40px;
      top: 35%;
      color: #00005e;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .playAgain {
      position: absolute;
      height: 40px;
      width: 150px;
      top: 65%;
      left: 40%;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
      background-color: #00005e;
      border-style: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    /*The 'DID YOU KNOW' over the ticker*/
    .facts {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #00005e;
    }

    /*The facts ticker*/
    .tcontainer {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
    }

    .ticker-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100%; 
    background-color: #00005e;
    }

    @keyframes ticker {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
    }
    .ticker-move {
     display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 100%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: ticker;
    animation-duration: 55s;
    }
    .ticker-move:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused; 
    }

    .ticker-item{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 3em;
    color: white;
    min-height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    }


    /*The pause button for the ticker*/
    .pause {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .pausebutton {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #00005e;
    color: white;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .pausebutton:hover {
    background-color: #3c3b6e;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>ok</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>THE PASSWORD GAME</h1>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="dropdownTips()" class="dropbtn">TIPS?</button>
                <div class="dropdowncontent" id="mydropdown" >
                    <ul>
                        <li class="passwordtips">Tips for making strong passwords: </li>
                        <li class="advise">1. Use 16 characters or more (use both uppercase and lowercase letters, number and symbols.)</li>
                        <li class="advise">2. Never use the same password twice.</li>
                        <li class="advise">3. Use a password manager.</li>
                        <li class="advise">4. Don't write your passwords down on paper.</li>
                        <li class="advise">5. Don't share your passwords with others.</li>
                        <li class="advise">6. Change your password after a breach.</li>
                        <li class="advise">7. Sign up for data breach notifications. (like <a href="https://haveibeenpwned.com/" target="_blank">haveibeenpwned.com</a>).</li>
                        <li class="advise">8. Check your accounts regularly for any suspicious activity. </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="score">Score:<span> 0</span></div>

        <section class="sectionOne">
            <div class="wrapper" id="card-deck">
                <div class="card" data-type="1"><h2>What information should you NEVER use in a password?</h2></div>
                <div id="answerSix" class="card"  data-type="6"><h2>1 log in</h2></div>
                <div id="cardThree" class="card"  data-type="3"><h2>When should you ALWAYS change your password?</h2></div>
                <div id="anserFive" class="card"  data-type="5"><h2>suspicious activity</h2></div>
                <div id="cardTwo" class="card"  data-type="2"><h2>Who is it okay to tell your password to?</h2></div>
                <div id="answerFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>16</h2></div>
                <div id="answerThree" class="card" data-type="3"><h2>After a data breach</h2></div>
                <div id="answerTwo" class="card" data-type="2"><h2>No one</h2></div>
                <div id="CardSix" class="card" data-type="6"><h2>For how many log ins is it okay to use the same password?</h2></div>
                <div id="cardFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>How many characters should you AT LEAST use in a password?</h2></div>
                <div class="card" data-card="firstSet" data-type="1"><h2>Name and Birthday</h2></div>
                <div id="cardFive" class="card" data-type="5"><h2>What should you regularly look for in your accounts?</h2></div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="popup">
            <h3 class="congrats">Congratulations!</h3>
            <h3 class="matches">You got 6/6 matches</h3>
            <button class="playAgain">Play again?</button>
        </section>

        <div class="facts">
            <h2>DID YOU KNOW?</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">
            <div class="ticker-item">There is a hacker attack every 39 seconds.</div>
            <div class="ticker-item">90% of passwords can be cracked in less than 6 hours.</div>
            <div class="ticker-item">80% of hacking related breaches are linked to insufficient passwords.</div>
            <div class="ticker-item">59% use their name or birthday in their password.</div>
            <div class="ticker-item">6.850.000 passwords are getting hacked each day.</div>
          </div></div></div>

        <div class="pause">
            <p>Hold your mouse over to pause</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And i changed the popup section to `id` instead of `class` like this

```html
 <section id="popup">
```

Comment: @AnnaEllegaardSkytte and dont forget to also change the css selector to `#popup` instead of `.popup`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
//Function for the dropdown content
function dropdownTips() {
    document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  
  window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowncontent");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  //the game
  
  // Declares global variables
  let score = 0,
    cardToMatch = null;
  
  // Calls `flipCard` on any click
  window.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
  
  
  // Defines the click listener
  function flipCard(event) {
  
    // Identifies the card where the click happened
    const card = event.target.closest(".card");
  
    // Ignores irrelevant/invalid clicks
    if (!card || card.classList.contains("open")) {
      return;
    }
  
    // A valid click always opens the card
    card.classList.add("open");
  
    // If this is the 1st card of 2, remember it
    if (cardToMatch === null) {
      cardToMatch = card;
    } else {
  
  
      // If it's the 2nd card, compare types
      // If they match...
      if (card.dataset.type === cardToMatch.dataset.type) {
  
        // ...Increment score and show it in the DOM
        updateScoreDisplay(++score);
      }
  
      // If they don't...
      else {
        // ...Flip both cards back over
        setTimeout((first, second) => {
          first.classList.remove("open");
          second.classList.remove("open");
          
        }, 3000, card, cardToMatch);
        
        // Either way, next click will be the 1st of 2
      }
      
      cardToMatch = null;
    }
  }
  
  function updateScoreDisplay(newScore) {
    // Syncs the user-displayed value w/ score
    const element = document.querySelector(".score span");
    element.textContent = newScore;
  }

  // popup section
  
setInterval(function() {if (score==6) {document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";}},1000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color:#00005e;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 38%;
  right: 40%;
  width: 355px;
}

/*The 'tips?' button and the drop down content*/
header button {
display: inline-flex;
position:absolute;
align-items: center;
right: 2%;
top: 15%;
bottom: 15%;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color:white;
color: #00005e;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
border-color: transparent;
}

header button:hover {
opacity: 80%;
}


.dropdowncontent {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
background-color:#010169;
min-width: 160px;
max-width: 400px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
z-index: 100;

}

.dropdowncontent li {
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.advise{
font-size: 19px;
}

.passwordtips {
font-size: 30px;
left: 20%;
}

.show {
display:block;
}

/*The link in the dropdowncontent*/
a {
text-decoration: underline;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

/*The score counter*/
.score {
  color: #01016e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/*The game section*/
.sectionOne {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #00005e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

/*The sections content*/
.wrapper {
width: 99%;
height: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 183px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.card{
background-color: #01016e;
color: white;
margin: 10px 10px;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.card h2{
  padding: 2px;
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}

.card:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.open{
animation: flip .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes flip {
from { 
  background: #00005e;
  font-size: 0;
}
to{
  background: rgb(20, 73, 185);
  font-size:17px;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
}

/* pop up section */
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 50.5vh;
  top: 14%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: none;
}

.congrats {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  top: 20%;
  color: #00005e;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.matches {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  top: 35%;
  color: #00005e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.playAgain {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 65%;
  left: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #00005e;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*The 'DID YOU KNOW' over the ticker*/
.facts {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 15px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #00005e;
}

/*The facts ticker*/
.tcontainer {
max-width: 1100px;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.ticker-wrap {
width: 100%;
padding-left: 100%; 
background-color: #00005e;
}

@keyframes ticker {
0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
.ticker-move {
 display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-right: 100%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: ticker;
animation-duration: 55s;
}
.ticker-move:hover{
animation-play-state: paused; 
}

.ticker-item{
display: inline-block; 
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-right: 3em;
color: white;
min-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
}


/*The pause button for the ticker*/
.pause {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.pausebutton {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #00005e;
color: white;
border-style: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.pausebutton:hover {
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>The Password Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>THE PASSWORD GAME</h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropdownTips()" class="dropbtn">TIPS?</button>
            <div class="dropdowncontent" id="mydropdown" >
                <ul>
                    <li class="passwordtips">Tips for making strong passwords: </li>
                    <li class="advise">1. Use 16 characters or more (use both uppercase and lowercase letters, number and symbols.)</li>
                    <li class="advise">2. Never use the same password twice.</li>
                    <li class="advise">3. Use a password manager.</li>
                    <li class="advise">4. Don't write your passwords down on paper.</li>
                    <li class="advise">5. Don't share your passwords with others.</li>
                    <li class="advise">6. Change your password after a breach.</li>
                    <li class="advise">7. Sign up for data breach notifications. (like <a href="https://haveibeenpwned.com/" target="_blank">haveibeenpwned.com</a>).</li>
                    <li class="advise">8. Check your accounts regularly for any suspicious activity. </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="score">Score:<span> 0</span></div>

    <section class="sectionOne">
        <div class="wrapper" id="card-deck">
            <div class="card" data-type="1"><h2>What information should you NEVER use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerSix" class="card"  data-type="6"><h2>1 log in</h2></div>
            <div id="cardThree" class="card"  data-type="3"><h2>When should you ALWAYS change your password?</h2></div>
            <div id="anserFive" class="card"  data-type="5"><h2>suspicious activity</h2></div>
            <div id="cardTwo" class="card"  data-type="2"><h2>Who is it okay to tell your password to?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>16</h2></div>
            <div id="answerThree" class="card" data-type="3"><h2>After a data breach</h2></div>
            <div id="answerTwo" class="card" data-type="2"><h2>No one</h2></div>
            <div id="CardSix" class="card" data-type="6"><h2>For how many log ins is it okay to use the same password?</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>How many characters should you AT LEAST use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div class="card" data-card="firstSet" data-type="1"><h2>Name and Birthday</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFive" class="card" data-type="5"><h2>What should you regularly look for in your accounts?</h2></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="popup" id="popup">
        <h3 class="congrats">Congratulations!</h3>
        <h3 class="matches">You got 6/6 matches</h3>
        <button class="playAgain">Play again?</button>
    </section>

    <div class="facts">
        <h2>DID YOU KNOW?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">There is a hacker attack every 39 seconds.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">90% of passwords can be cracked in less than 6 hours.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">80% of hacking related breaches are linked to insufficient passwords.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">59% use their name or birthday in their password.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">6.850.000 passwords are getting hacked each day.</div>
      </div></div></div>

    <div class="pause">
        <p>Hold your mouse over to pause</p>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason why your code wasn't working was because the code you had only checked if the `score` was 6 at the start of the game. I fixed this by using the function `setInterval` which checked if the user had finished the game every second.

#### More Explanations

If you would like to learn more about the `setInterval` function, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp